# JBoss Enterprise Application Platform vs JBoss Enterprise SOA Platform

Tags: jboss

What can JBoss EAP do that JBoss ESP cannot? or vice verse?

Is it correct to say JBoss EAP is a subset of JBoss ESP? Meaning JBoss ESP has all the features JBoss EAP has, plus the SOA stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the answer JBoss emailed to me.

JBoss SOA-P is a superset of JBoss EAP. Details such as version numbers are listed at http://www.jboss.com/products/platforms/soa/components/, but SOA-P is EAP plus an Enterprise Service Bus (ESB), Business Process Management engine (jBPM) and a Rules engine (Drools).

The SOA Platform can do everything that the underlying version of EAP can do.