# Can i install JBOSS SOA-P into existed JBOSS EAP 5.1?

Tags: ubuntu-server, jboss-esb

On my server UBUNTU SERVER 12.04 LTS, I installed **JBoss EAP 5.1**, and everything is working perfectly. Now I need to install JBOSS ESB, JBPM and JBoss Web Services. These 3 packages (except perhaps JBoss Web Services) are contained in **JBoss SOA-P 5.2**.
Given that JBoss SOA-P also contains JBoss EAP, how do I proceed? Is there a way to install individual packages missing, or can I install SOA-P on EAP? How?

Answer (score 2):

If you have SOA-P 5.2 then I would just install and use that.  EAP is included in the SOA-P and everything else you need, i.e. web services etc. should be in the jboss tools (I get them from the nightlies update site aka jboss soa tools).  What is your end goal?  Do you have a specific project or set of projects that are EAP specific?

also see this: [JBoss Enterprise Application Platform vs JBoss Enterprise SOA Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148735/jboss-enterprise-application-platform-vs-jboss-enterprise-soa-platform/4154256#4154256)